# Thread-safe last_insert_rowid with SQLite3 API (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

I have a program which handles a database with threads (according to user-requests). There is a problem though:

Although it is improbable, there's a chance for a problem when, for example, insert a user into a database (his details) and I want to find out his identifier column value (an `int`) using `sqlite3_int64 sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqlite*);` function.

Even though the API is generally thread-safe, as much as I researched - a problem could occur if another thread inserted a row into the same table **after** I inserted mine, but **before** I called `sqlite3_last_insert_row_id()`.

From the [SQLite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html):

> If a separate thread performs a new INSERT on the same database connection while the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() function is running and thus changes the last insert rowid, then the value returned by sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() is unpredictable and might not equal either the old or the new last insert rowid.

How do I prevent this?

I could mutex all of my database access but that would be quite troublesome at the current stage, is this the only way?

I could also do a transaction-sql query, but would that have the same effect I want?

Answer (score 3):

To prevent multiple threads from interfering with each others, you should use transactions, and one database connection for each thread.

If you really want to share the same connection between threads, you need a mutex.